# Fastest computation of sum x^5 + x^4 + x^3...+x^0 (Bitwise possible ?) with x=16

Tags: c, math, optimization, assembly, hpc

For a tree layout that takes benefit of cache line prefetching (`reading _next_ cacheline` is cheap), I need to solve the address calculation in a really fast way. I was able to boil down the problem to:

```
newIndex = nowIndex + 1 + (localChildIndex*X)
```

x would be for example: X = 4<sup>5</sup> + 4<sup>4</sup> + 4<sup>3</sup> + 4<sup>2</sup> +4<sup>0</sup>.

Note: 4 is the branching factor. In reality it will be 16, so a power of 2. This should be useful to use bitwise stuff?

It would be very bad if it would need a loop to calculate X (`performancewise`) and stuff like division/multiplication. This appeals to be an interesting problem which I wasn’t able to come up with some nice way of computing it.

Since its part of a tree traversal, 2 modes would be possible: absolute calculation, independent of prior calculations AND incremental calculation which starts with a high X being kept in a variable and then some minimal stuff done to it with every deeper level of the tree.

I hope I was able to make clear what the math should do. Not sure if there is a way to do this fast & without loop - but maybe somebody can come up with a really smart solution. I would like to thank everybody for their help - StackOverflow have been a great teacher to me in the past and I hope to be able to give back more in the future, as my knowledge increases.

Comment: Just to clarify: `^` is power or xor?

Comment: Identity: `X^n + X^(n-1) + ... + X^1 + X^0 = {X^(n + 1) - 1} / {X - 1}`

Comment: Also is `x` variable? Otherwise this would be trivial.

Comment: @Nabla - good point. If `x` is fixed, simply calculate once and store it.

Comment: Its power. Sorry, should have clarified. Yes, x is fixed because it depends on the branching factor (16 typically). I was thinking about a lookup table, too. Not sure though.

Comment: Well, if `x` is a power of 2, then so is `x^n`.  It's just a question of setting the relevant bit to `1`...

Comment: (111111)<<3 = 1 1111 1000 = decimal 1017

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll answer this in increasing complexity and generality.

- If x is fixed to 16 then just use a constant value `1118481`. Hooray! (Name it, using magical numbers is bad practice)
- If you have a few cases known at compile time use a few constants or even defines, for example:

  ```
  #define X_2 63
  #define X_4 1365
  #define X_8 37449
  #define X_16 1118481
  ...
  ```
- If you have several cases known at execution time initialize and use a lookup table indexed with the exponent.

  ```
  int _X[MAX_EXPONENT]; // note: give it a more meaningful name :)
  ```

  Initialize it and then just access with the known exponent of 2^exp at execution time.

  ```
  newIndex = nowIndex + 1 + (localChildIndex*_X[exp]);
  ```
- How are these values precalculated, or how to calculate them efficiently on the fly:
  The sum `X = x^n + x^(n - 1) + ... + x^1 + x^0` is a [geometric serie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) and its finite sum is:

  ```
  X = x^n + x^(n - 1) + ... + x^1 + x^0 = (1-x^(n + 1))/(1-x)
  ```
- About the bitwise operations, as Oli Charlesworth has stated if x is a power of 2 (in binary 0..010..0) `x^n` is also a power of 2, and the sum of *different* powers of two is equivalent to the OR operation. Thus we could make an expression like:

  Let `exp` be the exponent so that x = 2^exp. (For 16, exp = 4). Then,

  ```
  X = x^5 + ... + x^1 + x^0
  X = (2^exp)^5 + ... + (2^exp)^1 + 1
  X = 2^(exp*5) + ... + 2^(exp*1) + 1
  ```

  now using bitwise, `2^n = 1<<n`

  ```
  X = 1<<(exp*5) | ... | 1<<exp | 1
  ```

  In C:

  ```
  int X;
  int exp = 4; //for x == 16
  X = 1 << (exp*5) | 1 << (exp*4) | 1 << (exp*3) | 1 << (exp*2) | 1 << (exp*1) | 1;
  ```
- And finally, I can't resist to say: if your expression were more complex and you had to evaluate an arbitrary polynomial `a_n*x^n + ... + a_1*x^1 + a_0` in x, instead of implementing the obvious loop, a faster way to evaluate the polynomial is using the [Horner's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method).